# Condition for a function to be zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, functions

Suppose the following function :

$$f(x)=\frac{\theta}{2}g(-1)+(1-\theta)g(0)+\frac{\theta}{2}g(1),$$

where $g$  is some function.

Now it is written that if $g(-1)=g(1)$ and $g(0)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $\theta$.

But it seems to me if $g(-1)=g(1)$ and $g(0)=0$, then $f(x)\ne 0$. Because if I specified some value, say, $g(-1)=g(1)=1$ and $g(0)=0$, then $f(x)=\theta$.

Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: You're correct, there is probably a typo (missing minus sign somewhere) in the problem statement.